# Traverse a Map that has a vector and a Map as its second Node and find a match in the second Node's second element. C++

Tags: c++, maps

How can I iterate thru the second maps second node and find duplicates? 
With the code below I was expecting the second **for loop** to iterate 4 times since there are 4 Nodes in the outer map. However, after the first iteration of the second **for loop** I get a segfault. And Ideas?

```
void xmlParser::SortAndGroupByKey()
{
    bool match = true;
    std::map<std::vector<unsigned char>, std::vector<unsigned char>> tempMidNonceMap;

    std::map<std::vector<unsigned char>, std::vector<unsigned char>>::iterator keyIt= m_mapMidNonceKey.begin()->second.begin();
    //Iterate thru the second maps second element
    for(std::map<std::vector<unsigned char>, std::map<std::vector<unsigned char>, std::vector<unsigned char>>>::iterator mapIt=m_mapMidNonceKey.begin(); mapIt != m_mapMidNonceKey.end(); ++mapIt)
    {
        //innerMapit points to the inner(2nd Map) map iterator
        for(std::map<std::vector<unsigned char>, std::vector<unsigned char>>::iterator innerMapit= mapIt->second.begin(); innerMapit != mapIt->second.end(); ++innerMapit)
        {
            for(size_t i = 0; i < innerMapit->second.size(); ++i)
            {
                if(innerMapit->second[i] != keyIt->second[i]) //Do they match?
                {
                    match = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(match)
            {
                //Make a pair of the values
                tempMidNonceMap.insert(std::make_pair(mapIt->first,innerMapit->first)); 
            }
        }
        //Check to see if the key already exists in the map if it does then only insert 
        if(!DuplicateKeyExists(keyIt->second))
        {
            this->m_mapKey.insert(std::make_pair(keyIt->second, tempMidNonceMap));
        }
        tempMidNonceMap.clear();
        keyIt++;
        match = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: The Map of Map was not in the format that I "thought" I was populating it. I was adding many smaller maps to the outer map.

Answer (score 0):

You may have out of bound accesses with

```
innerMapit->second[i] != keyIt->second[i]
```

for `keyIt->second[i]`

The simplest fix should be to use

```
const bool match = (innerMapit->second != keyIt->second);
```

instead of

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < innerMapit->second.size(); ++i)
{
    if(innerMapit->second[i] != keyIt->second[i]) //Do they match?
    {
        match = false;
        break;
    }
}
```